# Nest.js: how to override providers in an imported module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

### Code example

Third party library

```
@Module({
    providers: [AService]
    exports: [AService]
})
export class AModule {
}

@Module({
    imports: [AModule],
    providers: [BService]
    exports: [BService]
})
export class BModule {
}
```

My code

```
@Module({
    imports: [BModule],
    providers: [CService]
})
export class CModule {
}
```

### Question

How can I override/replace the `AService` provider from my code? (without third party library patching)

Comment: Firstly, why would you want to? I would recommend making your module dynamic and accepting a provider of a certain instance you can use

Comment: @bashleigh it's legit what he want. He has an external dependency, say `A`, and he wants to inject a custom service into it. He can't patch the external library. How would you inject a service you coded into the "DI system" of the imported module WITHOUT changing the imported module?

Comment: Take a look at this DynamicModule implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663183/409604

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, this is how you would go about making a dynamic module with a dynamic provider

```js
export interface ProviderInterface {
  handle(): void;
}

@Injectable()
class SomeHandlingProvider {
  constructor(@Inject('MY_DYNAMIC_PROVIDER') private readonly dynamicProvider: ProviderInterface) {}
  handle(): void {
    this.dynamicProvider.handle();
  }
}

@Module({})
export class AModule {
  public static forRoot(provider: ProviderInstance): DynamicModule {
    return {
       module: AModule,
       providers: [
         {
           provide: 'MY_DYNAMIC_PROVIDER',
           useClass: provider,
         },
         SomeHandlingProvider,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can use like this

```js
class GenericDynamicProviderExample implements ProviderInterface {
  handle(): void {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    AModule.forRoot(GenericDynamicProviderExample),
  ],
})
export class BModule {}
```

Comment: this isn't answering the question. The OP specifically said "without patching the imported module"

Answer (score 0):

If you try something like this:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AService,
      useClass: AClassOverride,
    },
  ],
})
export class CModule {}
```

The service will be overridden in the `CModule`, not the `AModule`. To change the service
inside the `AModule` you need to use a `DynamicModule`.

```js
import {
  DynamicModule,
  Injectable,
  Module,
  ModuleMetadata,
} from "@nestjs/common";

export type AModuleAsyncOptions = {
  imports?: ModuleMetadata["imports"];
  inject: any[];
  aServiceFactory: (...args: any[]) => Promise<AService> | AService;
};

@Module({
  providers: [AService],
  exports: [AService],
})
export class AModule {
  static registerAsync(options: AModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: AModule,
      imports: options.imports,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AService,
          useFactory: options.aServiceFactory,
          inject: options.inject,
        },
      ],
      exports: [AService],
    };
  }
}
```

Now you can provide your own dependency from `BModule`.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    AModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ServiceModuleOverride], // import the module that haves the dependency that you want to override
      inject: [AServiceOverride], // Inject the service
      aServiceFactory: (aServiceOverride: AServiceOverride) => {
        return aServiceOverride; // return the service
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class BModule {}
```

If you want to override `CModule` you can do what I did in `AModule` in `BModule` and pass down the
`inject`, `imports`, and the `factory`.