# Override provider from another Nestjs module

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to use a custom provider in NestJS to override the original service implementation with a new implementation (such as the example of the CatsService in the documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#custom-providers-1), but it's not injecting the new implementation, it's injecting the original implementation.

I've created an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-shvmer?file=src/app.module.ts

Instead of showing "NEW SERVICE" in the web page, it's still showing "Hello World"!

What an I missing?

other-module.ts:

```typescript
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [AppService]
})
export class OtherModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```typescript
class NewService extends AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'NEW SERVICE';
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [OtherModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AppService,
      useClass: NewService,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As informed by Jay McDoniel, the custom providers are only visible in the same module context where the service depending on it is declared, so what I want to do is not possible.

The solution I found was to use DynamicModule in the imported modules and pass the custom providers for them:

**app-module.ts**

```typescript
@Module({
  imports: [OtherModule.register({provide: AppService, useClass: NewService})],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**other-module.ts**

```typescript
@Module({ 
})
export class OtherModule { 

  static register(appServiceProvider: Provider<any>):DynamicModule{
    return {  
      module: OtherModule,
      imports: [],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [appServiceProvider],
      exports: [AppService],
    }
  }
}
```

In my real app, I also needed to pass the entire dynamic module object for other imported modules (that also need to be a DynamicModule) so anywhere the custom provider is needed it was reached by nestjs injection resolution.

Not a very clean solution, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

`OtherModule` is where your `AppController` is dedfined, so `OtherModule` is where `AppService` will **first** be searched for. Nest doesn't search in "parent" modules for providers, but the other way around. If Nest does not find the proper provider in the current module, then the imported modules' `exports` arrays will be searched, and then the global modules' `exports` will be searched. If you want to do something like this, then you need to make `AppModule` have the `AppController` and have `OtherModule` have the standard `AppService` while `AppModule` has the overriding `AppService` using the custom provider.

Comment: But isn't the purpose of the custom providers to offer a way of overriding the providers for the whole application? For example, the documentation itself gives the following example for when to use custom provider: "You want to override a class with a mock version for testing". Or the CatService example in the doc, it shows how to use a mocked CatService direct on AppModule, without having the controllers and other services in the app-module itself.

Comment: We should make the docs clearer that __in the AppModule context__ `CatsService` will resolve to that mock. As for providing mocks for testing, that is a common use case, and is [used in the `TestingModule`](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/main/apps/complex-sample/src/cat/cat.controller.spec.ts)